# Custom hit-test on UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have chat UI based on `UICollectionView`. Very common `UI` that looks like iMessage. 
I have logic that handles taps on chat message bubbles using

```
collectionView(_:didSelectItemAt:)
```

I want to add tap gesture recognizer to the background of this collection view to dismiss keyboard.

So I want to customize hit testing on my `bubbleCell`, so I will be able to tap on bubble to call

```
collectionView(_:didSelectItemAt:)
```

and to tap on empty space to call close keyboard logic.

What should I do to achieve this behaviour?

**Upd. Some code**

If I add tap gesture to the ChatViewController.view

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    // ...
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ChatViewController.dismissKeyboard))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

func dismissKeyboard() {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

This code will never being called

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Handle tap on cell
}
```

Comment: Show some code what you are trying ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need to set `cancelTouchesInView` to false on your `UITapGestureRecognizer` in order to recognize both taps (on Collection View and your Tap Gesture Recognizer).

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ChatViewController.dismissKeyboard))
tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Comment: It works for me, thanks! But I also had to override - (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(nullable UIEvent *)event; method to check whether user tap on bubble or free space in the cell